Snowflake SQL: Select all rows for Patients who have a RowNum > 1
My SQL creates a list with Row Numbers based on PatientID and EncounterDate.
Patients who have two Encounters on a single date will have two rows - with Row Numbers 1 & 2.
How can I show only Rows for Patients who have two or more Encounters on the same date?
For example, if they have 3 Encounters on one day, I want to see all 3.
For example:
PatientID     EncounterDate
111            2024-08-01
111            2024-08-01
111            2024-08-01
111            2024-08-02
111            2024-08-03
222            2024-08-01
333            2024-08-01
444            2024-08-01 

In the case of the above data, I want to only see all 3 rows for PatientID 111 - for 2024-08-01. I hope this helps.
Thanks in advance!

you can use Count windows function in Snowflake and pick up rows where count(*) > 2.
create or replace table test as      
select '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-02' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-03' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '222' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '333' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '444' as PatientID  , to_date('            2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate  ;

select * from (
select PatientID,EncounterDate, count(*) over (partition by PatientID,EncounterDate) cnt
from test )where cnt > 2;

or you can use Qualify
select * from test
QUALIFY count(*) over (partition by PatientID,EncounterDate) > 2;


Thank you. First, I changed >2 to > 1. Second, your suggestion will not give me the rows with a count of 1. I need ALL rows for patients who have more than one row on the same date. I hope I didn't miss something in your suggestion.

Hi, can you please send us some sample data and expected output that would help.

I added some sample data to my original post. I hope it helps.

Hi, i updated the answer with your sample data.

You can do this simply with this sql statement:
I have provide you the link to see the result_sql
SELECT t.PatientID, t.EncounterDate
FROM encounters t
JOIN (
    SELECT PatientID, EncounterDate
    FROM encounters
    GROUP BY PatientID, EncounterDate
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) AS filtered
ON t.PatientID = filtered.PatientID
AND t.EncounterDate = filtered.EncounterDate;

Here is the result
PatientID   EncounterDate
111          2024-08-01
111          2024-08-01
111          2024-08-01


You can use Window function to get the multiple entries on the same date, Below sample SQL would work for this.
WITH SRC AS (
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-02' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '111' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-03' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '222' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '333' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate UNION ALL
SELECT '444' as PatientID  , to_date('2024-08-01' ,'yyyy-dd-mm') as EncounterDate
)

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM SRC
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PATIENTID,ENCOUNTERDATE ORDER BY ENCOUNTERDATE) > 1;

You will get below output
PATIENTID   ENCOUNTERDATE
111         2024-01-08

